# Why does Gabor filter thinning when i change angle

Tags: go, image-processing, gabor-filter

I have this code in GO

```
func gaborFilter(kernelSize int, sigma float64, theta float64, lambda float64, psi float64, gamma float64) GaborFilter {
   kernel := make([][]float64, kernelSize)
   for i := range kernel {
      kernel[i] = make([]float64, kernelSize)
   }

   for y := 0; y < kernelSize; y++ {
      for x := 0; x < kernelSize; x++ {
         mathX := float64(x) - float64(kernelSize-1)/2
         mathY := float64(y) - float64(kernelSize-1)/2
         xTheta := mathX*math.Cos(theta) + mathY*math.Sin(theta)
         yTheta := -mathX*math.Sin(theta) + mathY*math.Cos(theta)

         kernel[y][x] = math.Exp(-(xTheta*xTheta+gamma*gamma*yTheta*yTheta)/(2*sigma*sigma)) * math.Cos(2*math.Pi*xTheta/lambda+psi)
      }
   }
   filter.Kernel = kernel

   return filter
}
```

Here is call:

```
filter := gaborFilter(15, 3.0, avgDirection, math.Pi/4, 0.0, 1.0)
```

Here is mathematical function:

[image: Gabor filter function]

But it works nice only with certain angles, for example 45 degrees. And when I increment angle, lines of the filter start thinning. In other web-resources I didn't see this behavior of gabor filters. In articles they've just rotated, as I want in my case.

Here is an example of my filters (i need smth like 1nd and 2nd, but not 3rd and 4th)

[image: my filters]

I'm new to image processing and it's hard to me to understand my mistake. Help me please.

Comment: It would be good if you showed the function calls you used to generate those kernels. Maybe your lambda is so small you're seeing aliasing?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Updated topic. Honestly, idk why here is lambda pi/4. I saw it in one of the videos. Man said that this lamda is good for angled filters. As i know, lambda responsible for line width.

Comment: @CrisLuengo even in opencv2 for python when I used cv2.getGaborKernel() with similar values, it returned that kind of filters. Maybe problem is in my values?